# A term to represent a moment in time (date and time)

Tags: naming

For example, I want to use a shorter word for `EventDateAndTime` property. 
Is there such word in English language?

I am not after shorter word. I am after a concise one.

> naming is one of the hardest things
>   in programming

Comment: Is this one for the English stackexchange? http://english.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: I'd say this if off-topic for SO, but the best place for it, English.SE, might consider it off-topic too.

Comment: so, who else thinks that naming is important in software development and programmind?

Answer (score 3):

"DateTime" is often used for this. "Timepoint" or "timestamp", while being an actual words, aren't any shorter.

Answer (score 3):

How about "timestamp"?

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp):

> A timestamp is a sequence of
>   characters, denoting the date and/or
>   time at which a certain event
>   occurred. A timestamp is the time at
>   which an event is recorded by a
>   computer, not the time of the event
>   itself. In many cases, the difference
>   may be inconsequential: the time at
>   which an event is recorded by a
>   timestamp (e.g., entered into a log
>   file) should be very, very close to
>   the time of the occurrence of the
>   event recorded.

Answer (score 1):

Would `timeStamp` suffice?

And don't be afraid of long variable names if they don't create problems.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using "timestamp".  It's short, clear, and to the point.

Answer (score 1):

I think `Instant` suffix can carry all semantics you want to express

Comment: I'd prefer this because "timestamp" has the connotation of being specifically the numeric representation.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use your own term: `Moment`? `Instant`? Just `Event`? Event implies something that happens at some time.

Answer (score 0):

How about `Juncture`?

> a point of time, especially one made
>   critical or important by a concurrence
>   of circumstances.